# Double gang outlets on kitchen counter branch?

Tags: wiring, kitchens

Are there NEC restrictions which would prevent me from installing "quad" outlet(s) in double gang boxes (vs. the more common duplex outlet/single gang box configuration) in the two required 20A kitchen counter GCFI protected circuits for new construction?  All the tutorials I've viewed depict duplex outlets only for this application.

Comment: I don't think double gang boxes would not be allowed, but I doubt if double gang will not reduce the need to have outlets at certain distance from each other.  You would still need another outlet at 6 or 12 feet away(not sure) from the double gang.  I would have each single double outlet on a different circuit in the double gang box.

Comment: @crip659 The OP specified countertop, the rule for countertops is max spacing 24" [210.52(C)(1)]   https://up.codes/viewer/washington/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.52_(C)_(1)

Comment: I exclusively installed quad receptacles on my kitchen counter during a recent remodel and I also arranged the circuitry such that each box has two circuits in it. Thus I can put high draw appliances into one quad box when occasions require. The left receptacle in each box is circuit A, the right is circuit B. Coincidentally I also have circuits C and D on the opposite counter because I went overboard in my large galley kitchen.

Comment: My terminology above was wrong, no point can be further than 24", which could be 48" spacing. I did the quad A/B C/D layout when I did my kitchen too, plus 12/3 for disp/dw and I argued with myself about using 14/3 for frid/mic, but couldn't bring myself to break pattern for one run even though I knew it would've been enough!

Answer (score 4):

You can *and should* install quad outlets wherever you anticipate having more than two appliances parked on the counter.  This is vastly preferable to placing a power bar on the counter top or constantly plugging and unplugging them.

Don't plan on placing all your heating appliances on one circuit this way.  A toaster, coffee maker, and tea kettle cannot all work on one circuit.

But an electric can opener, a bluetooth speaker, knife sharpener, charger for land line phone, USB charging station, milk frother, mini food processor, digital photo frame, etc etc ... if these things will have a place on the counter, it's great to leave them all plugged in, the cords tidy and no splitters or adapters.

Answer (score 3):

I checked with the local inspector and there was no problem and as suggested I ran a separate circuit for each duplex. At the start I put two GFCI breakers one for each 20A circuit (fed with separate breakers in main panel as well). I then daisy chained 12x2/G to each duplex keeping each side separate. I used extra deep boxes as the inspector had suggested. It went in easy and is working great. I can plug an oven and coffee pot in side by side with no trips. The complete remodel passed inspection the first pass. I like them green tags.